# Are JSONDecoder and JSONEncoder classes thread-safe?

Tags: ios, swift, thread-safety

i couldn't find any evidence that would suggest either way.

i'm currently creating new instances each time and configuring them with custom decoding/encoding options, and wondered if i could create a singleton and vend it each time i need it.

Comment: Good question. I don't know the answer tho. (I'm assuming that they are, since usually non UIKit frameworks that are **not** thread-safe are called out in the docs and these aren't.)

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to test. Create a really large complicated data model and one JSONEncoder. Then try to concurrently call `encode` from two different threads and see the result on both threads comes out correctly or not. Basically, as long as the implementation of `encode` doesn't write to any private instance variables, then `JSONEncoder` would be thread-safe. Isn't the source code for this available?

Comment: you're right @rmaddy, i can go look at the source code. i guess i was being lazy, shame on me. And your suggestion to test it out would be a definitive way to verify it. Much appreciate your response.

Comment: Actually, looking at the source code is the definitive way. The test code would only be definitive if the test shows there is a problem. If the test does not show a problem it doesn't necessarily mean that it's really thread safe, just that the test didn't find it.

Comment: roger that @rmaddy.

Comment: And did anybody look at the source and has the answer?

Answer (score 10):

Judging by the code for `JSONDecoder` and `JSONEncoder` they seem to be thread-safe.

Both `encode()` and `decode()` use `JSONSerialization` (which has been thread-safe since iOS 7 and macOS 10.9), and both methods create their own private decode/encode objects in local variables. There is no shared storage as far as I can see.

The code can be found here:
https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Sources/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift

Comment: Source for JSONEncoder.swift is now at https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift